# Can't enable android keyboard voice input

Tags: android, keyboard, android-5.0-lollipop, voice-recognition

I have a nexus 4 with the latest 5.1 Lollipop.  Ever since I upgraded to android 5 I haven't had the voice input option on my keyboard. In the Keyboard settings - preferences, Voice Input is greyed out, and it says "no voice input methods selected".  But under Settings-Language and Input - keyboard settings there's no entry for Google Voice Typing.

Interestingly, I created a second 'test' user account on my phone, and that user has the Google Voice Typing setting - it's set to automatic.  And the keyboard has the microphone icon - and the preference to enable/disable it.

The test user isn't using the Google Now launcher - it doesn't get that option.  So I tried disabling (and even uninstalling) the Now launcher for the main user, and it doesn't change anything.  For what it's worth, the main user can do 'OK Google' voice search, and the Google search widget has the microphone.  It's just the keyboard that doesn't.

Any idea how to get the microphone back?